# c++ - operator[] not working properly with handmade stack of structs?

Tags: c++, struct, stack, operator-overloading

I am learning memory management and made handmade stack in the heap with structs. That part works, but then I decided to also try learning operator overloading, and decided to try making all elements accessible (in O(n) time, I know) with the [] operator. However, for some reason, while stack->operator works more or less properly, stack[i] with i other than 0 gives a seemingly random number. Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct stackElem
{
    int v;
    stackElem *p;
    stackElem(){
        v = 0;
        p = nullptr;
    }
    ~stackElem(){
        delete p;
        p = nullptr;
    }
    int& operator[](size_t index) {
        if(index == 0) return this->v;
        stackElem *temp = this->p;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < index; i++){
            temp = temp->p;
        }
        return temp->v;
    }   //stack[0] returns top, then goes down
    const int operator[](size_t index) const {
        if(index == 0) return this->v;
        stackElem *temp = this->p;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < index; i++){
            temp = temp->p;
        }
        return temp->v;
    }
};

void stackPush(stackElem *&top, int val){
    stackElem *temp = top;
    top = new stackElem;
    top->v = val;
    top->p = temp;

}   //First in, last out

int stackPop(stackElem *&top){
    int ret = top->v;
    stackElem *temp = top->p;
    top->p = nullptr;
    delete top;
    top = temp;
    return ret;
}

int main(){
    stackElem *list = new stackElem;
    stackPush(list, 13);
    stackPush(list, 14);
    stackPush(list, 15);
    stackPush(list, 16);
    stackPush(list, 17);
    stackPush(list, 18);
    
    std::cout<<list->p->v<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<list[0].v<<"\t"<<list[1].v<<std::endl;//<<list[2].v<<list[3].v<<list[4].v<<list[5].v;
    list->operator[](1) = 100;   //This works correctly
    int test = list->operator[](1);   //This works correctly
    int test2 = list[1];   //This breaks
    std::cout<<test<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<list[1];   //This breaks
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I have 2 overloads (for int = stack[] and for stack[] = int, as I saw somewhere else). The one returning consts doesn't allow stackElem *temp = this because "You can't initialise stackElem * with const stackElem *", thet's why I use the funny if(index == 0) and assign temp to this->p.

Comment: Your `list` is a *pointer* not a class object. Change to `int test2 = (*list)[1];` and try again.

Comment: Why do you use a reference to a pointer in your function parameters? It's an odd choice. If you want to assign a new value to the argument then simply make your function return it and don't use an out parameter that way. It makes the code hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `int test2 = list[1];`, the subscript operator is the builtin subscript operator of pointers, i.e. given a pointer `stackElem*` and an offset `int`, it yields the `stackElem`, offset from the start. This is exactly like the subscript operator for arrays.

To call your own overloaded `operator[]`, you would have to dereference the pointer first:

```cpp
(*list)[1] // or
list[0][1]
```

#### Further Notes

- `const int operator[](size_t index) const` should return a reference instead of a value, since the non-const overload does that. This ensures that you can always take the address of the returned `int`.
- You have a destructor but no copy constructor or copy assignment operator (those are implicitly defaulted). [Remember the rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/5740428).
- It is inconvenient for the user of your stack if they have to `new` and `delete` themselves. Prefer encapsulating memory management, similar to `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You should redesign your code. `stackElem` should be hidden element of implementation detail. You need class which have minimum functionality.

Something like this:

```cpp
class Stack
{
   struct Element;
   std::unique_ptr<Element> root;

public:
   Stack();
   Stack(const Stack&) = delete;
   ~Stack();

   Stack& operator=(const Stack&) = delete;

   void push(int value);
   int pop();
   bool isEmpty() const;
   int operator[](size_t index) const;
};
```

`struct Stack::Element;` can be completely hidden in cpp file and other translation unit will see only `class Stack`.

BTW since C++11 you should not use `new`/`delete` explicitly. In your case use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique` (C++14). Let smart pointers take over.

[C++ Core Guidelines: R.11: Avoid calling `new` and `delete` explicitly](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly).

Comment: What is ```Stack(const Stack&) = delete;``` ?

Comment: disables copy constructor.